# Когда объявлять конструкторы с несколькими параметрами explicit?

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, инициализация

В каких случаях стоит объявлять конструкторы с несколькими параметрами `explicit`?

В большинстве кода и гайдах, что я видел, только конструкторы с 1 параметром по умолчанию объявляют `explicit`, однако Google [рекомендует](https://abseil.io/tips/142) объявлять `explicit` любые конструкторы, параметры которых не представляют значения класса. Например, конструкторы классов-контейнеров, принимающие итераторы на начало и конец какой-то последовательности, из которой необходимо заполнить контейнер. Это позволит избежать ошибок вида `std::vector<char> v = {"hello", "world"};`.

Comment: Фактически, вторая половина вашего вопроса, являетс ответом на него.

Comment: @gbg ну я хочу послушать, что считают другие люди. Почему только в 1 гайде об этом сказано, может они не правы в чём-то

Comment: @Stas, если покопаться,  то наверняка найдете где еще об этом сказано, потому что так оно и есть.  Нужно заранее анализировать или после выявления побочных эффектов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например всем знакомым std::ifstream имеет такой конструктор:

```
explicit basic_ifstream(
    const char*, ios_base::openmode, int)
```

Не трудно догадаться почему конструктор сделан явным _ лишить возможности  инициализировать универсальным инициализатором, не то получать проблем и неразберихи не сложно(еще один пример есть в вашем вопросе).

В каких случаях стоит объявлять конструкторы с несколькими параметрами explicit?

До появления универсального инициализатора не нужно было, но теперь:

**всегда, кроме случаев, когда неявное преобразование семантически оправдано.**